# What happens when you set a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I was trying out some ideas to solve an unrelated problem when I came across this behavior when using set on a dictionary:

```
a = {"a": 1}

b = {"b": 2}

c = {"a": 1}

set([a, b, c])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-7c1da7b47bae> in <module>
----> 1 set([a, b, c])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

set(d)
Out[23]: {'a', 'b'}

set(a)
Out[24]: {'a'}
```

I kind of understand why the set of dictionaries is unhashable (they're mutable), but the whole thing does not make that much sense to me. Why is `set(a)` and `set(d)` returning just the keys and how would that be useful?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you need a `set` of the keys... Note that `list(a)`, similarly, returns a list of the keys, and that iterating on the dict iterates on its keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` converts an arbitrary iterable to a set, which means getting an iterator for its argument. The iterator for a `dict` returns its keys. It's not so much about `set` being useful with a `dict`, but `set` not *caring* what its argument is.

As for why a `dict` iterator returns the keys of the `dict`, it's a somewhat arbitrary choice made by the language designer, but keep in mind that given the choice of iterating over the keys, the values, or the key-value pairs, iterating over the keys is probably the best compromise between usefulness and simplicity. (All three are available explicitly via `d.keys()`, `d.values()`, and `d.items()`; in some sense `iter(d)` is a convenience for the common use case of `d.keys()`.)

Answer (score 2):

The function `set(x)` takes any iterable `x` and puts all the iterated values into a set.

Dictionaries are iterable. When you iterate through a dictionary, you are given the keys. So `set(d)` will give you a new set containing all the keys of the dict `d`.